# C#: How to design a generic class so that the type parameter must inherit a certain class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics

I've written a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
       T.somethingSpecial;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because the compiler has no idea what T is.  I would like to constrain T so that it must inherit a certain class that defines `somethingSpecial`.  Bonus points if you can tell me how to do the same thing by contraining T so that it must implement a certain interface.

Comment: C# uses generics, not templates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: IAmSomethingSpecial
```

It's called [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use the following type parameter constraint in the class declaration:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass
```

You can read more about type parameter contraints for example [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : SomeParentClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Generic Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
  public void doSomething()
  {
    instanceOfT.somethingSpecial();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation. Generic Constraint.

```
class MyClass<T> where T : someinterfaceorbaseclassthatTmustinherit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class MyClass<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
       T.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The `where` keyword allows you to specify constraints on the given generic type. You could swap out the interface for a class.